# VBA code suggestion for looping through 2 ranges and autofilling another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm struggling to even visualise what kind of VBA code would suit this requirement let along google it.

I have a need to create differently named users for several owning teams on a range of different servers. My data consists of worksheets assigned one to each team, a list of usernames and a list of servers.

What I need to do is take the username range and server name range and combine them in expanding lists.

So this ;

```
Username1   Server1
Username2   Server2
Username3   Server3
Username4   Server4
Username5   Server5
Username6   Server6
Username7   Server7
Username8   Server8
Username9   Server9
```

Becomes this;

```
Username1   Server1 Username1   Server2
Username2   Server1 Username2   Server2
Username3   Server1 Username3   Server2
Username4   Server1 Username4   Server2
Username5   Server1 Username5   Server2
Username6   Server1 Username6   Server2
Username7   Server1 Username7   Server2
Username8   Server1 Username8   Server2
Username9   Server1 Username9   Server2
```

My thoughts were initially to look at doing a FOR-EACH loop across the Server range copying each value out to my Master sheet, then iterate over the usernames listed for that server but quickly got lost In Google. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Loop through the usernames and put them as the key in a dictionary. Have the item of the dictionary be an array of the servers. Loop through the dictionary and stick the servers next to the usernames.

Comment: Please note that a post as a discussion piece is not appropriate for this forum.  If you would update your post to be less subjective, focused on a specific answer, that will aid getting an answer.  Try a dictionary so you can get "unique" names, which might help get you to some code that can be used to update your post (edited, apparently @Warcupine had the same idea)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub ExpandData()
Dim Source1 As Range
Set Source1 = Worksheets(1).Range("a1") 'first username
Dim Source2 As Range
Set Source2 = Worksheets(1).Range("B1") 'first server
Dim target As Range
Set target = Worksheets(2).Range("a1")
Dim x As Long
Dim y As Long
For x = Source1.Row To Source1.End(xlDown).Row
    For y = Source2.Row To Source2.End(xlDown).Row
       target.Offset(y, (x * 2) - 1) = Source1.Offset(x - 1, 0)
       target.Offset(y, (x * 2)) = Source2.Offset(y - 1, 0)
    Next y
Next x
 'edit to move stuff to vertical
  With Worksheets(2)
    y = .Range("d2").End(xlDown).Row 'capture last rownumber
    For x = 4 To .Range("d2").End(xlToRight).Column Step 2
        .Range(.Cells(2, x), .Cells(y, x + 1)).Copy .Range("b2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
    Next x
    x = .Range("d2").End(xlToRight).Column 'capture last column number
    .Range("d2:" & .Cells(y, x).Address).Clear 'blank columns
End With


End Sub
```

Comment: At the risk of being cheeky and necro threading... What values would I need to change to do 2 vertical column lists rather than the more horizontal output?